# No screens found with usable configuration (Live-CD), boot-repair CLI

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, xorg, uefi, lightdm

I have an MSi GE70 Laptop (Graphics: nvidia GeForce GT650M). At first I couldn't boot nor install. After adding 'nomodeset' in Grub I was able to start the installation. `Try Ubuntu`` just gave me a blank screen.

I installed a dualboot with Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 8.1, UEFI, secure boot off (UEFI with CSM).

After the installation was a success, the computer boots straight into Windows. I knew this could happen and need to run boot-repair from the live-CD. Unfortunately I can't find a way to do this from CLI, since I get a blank screen in X I cannot use it's GUI.

I tried installing `nvidia-current` when booted with the live-CD, restarting lightdm (/etc/init.d/lightdm stop/start). No luck.

Trying to diagnose the problem this are the things I found:
`/var/log/lightdm/x-0.log` ends like this:

```
(EE) Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found
(EE)
(EE) Please consult the The X.org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help
(EE) Please also chech the log file at /var/log/Xorg.0.log for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Looking at `/var/log/xorg.0.log` I noticed:

```
[  1867.351] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[  1867.351] (EE) VESA(0): V_BIOS address 0x0 out of range
[  1867.351] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[  1867.351] (II) UnloadSubModule: "int10"
[  1867.351] (II) Unloading "int10"
[  1867.351] (II) UnloadSubModule: "vbe"
[  1867.351] (II) Unloading "vbe"
[  1867.351] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[  1867.351] (EE) Fatal server error
[  1867.351] (EE) no screens found
[  1867.351] (EE) Please consult the The X.org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help.
[  1867.351] (EE) Please also chech the log file at /var/log/Xorg.0.log for additional information.
[  1867.351] (EE)
[  1867.351] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

So I am trying to run Boot-repair, but I'm stuck because I can't get the GUI working with the live-CD. I've added `nomodeset`, tried `xforcevesa`.

Can anybody help me with either Boot-repair from CLI or graphics in live-CD? For me it's weird that the installation is able to show a nice GUI where the live-CD doesn't find a screen.

If I am able to boot into installed Ubuntu, I probably will run into the same graphics problems, but maybe it's easier to fix them on an installed version?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar problem.  I only recently updated my packages, so it could be related.  I fixed it with a full purge and reinstall of the nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get -y purge --auto-remove nvidia.*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install nvidia-current-updates nvidia-settings-updates
```

Worth a try.  Probably remove any /etc/X11/xorg.conf if you have one of those.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try using the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) If you did *not* use a separate `/boot` partition, it should boot up both Linux and Windows with no extra configuration required. You can then install rEFInd to your hard disk by installing the Debian-package version and experiment with boot options and X configuration options from your regular installation, which is likely to be better than experimenting with a live CD.

As to the X configuration, try this in a text-mode login:

1. Type `sudo su`. This will log you in as `root`.
2. Type `Xorg -configure`. This should create a file called `/root/xorg.conf.new`.
3. Copy `/root/xorg.conf.new` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.
4. Type `startx` to launch X.

At this point you can begin debugging. X might or might not start. If it does, log out and reboot, which should bring up X normally. If X doesn't start, though, consult any guide you can find on configuring `xorg.conf`. (I don't have any URLs handy, but I'm sure a Web search will turn up dozens of them.) You'll probably have to adjust the `Screen` section, and specifically change the `Driver` line to tell it to use whatever driver works for your system. (The `fbdev` driver will probably work, but with poor speed. The `nv` driver might work with better speed or not at all; and `nouveau` could provide still better speed or fail completely. If you install the Nvidia proprietary driver, it might or might not work; I believe its driver name is `nvidia`.) You may also need to adjust the `ServerLayout` section to remove unused `Screen` devices.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried command `update-grub` than restart,

if that does not help,
try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Why grub if the failure is in the graphic driver?